# How to load image stored in file using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I made this program to load images stored in a file but it isn't working.  I am working in Eclipse and using OpenCV.  I don't know what's the problem.  Can you help me please?

```
vector<Mat> images;

int number;

cin >> number;
for (int i=0; i< number; i++)
{
    string name = format("/home//ghalia//essai3//essai3/src//dossierimages//.jpg", i);
            Mat img= imread (name);

    if(img.empty())
    {
        cerr << "name"<< name << "erreur de chargement: " << endl;

        continue;
    }
    images.push_back(img);
        // show result:
       // imshow("test",img);

    imshow ("test", images[0]);
        waitKey(0);              // yes, you need the waitKey()
}
```

Comment: I'm trying hard to understand what you want, but just looking to your code I can see that you forget to insert the name of the image. `/home/ghalia/essai3/essai3/src/dossierimages/[the name of the image goes here].jpg` - You're forgetting a simple step of programming: Debugging.

Comment: Also you do not need double slashes in your path.

Comment: I do not fit the image name because I want to retrieve images that are in a folder that contains the image and a test file containing the names of the images.
you have an idea how to do, please?

Comment: @GhaliaDehag - You need to be more precise in your questions, you don't mention that above. But what you mean with retrieve images that are in the folder? All at the same time or you will specify the image somewhere somehow? Just like passing as argument to the application or what?

Comment: @GhaliaDehag Your comment sounds like you want to load the file name strings from a separate file.  That would be a different question from what you've asked here and what your code is set up to do.

Comment: I have three images saved in a folder, I need to download them for the purpose of merging and build a HDR images according Debevec algorithm. do you have idea, please?

Comment: @GhaliaDehag Again, that's a totally different question.  Help us to help you figure out this problem first, then ask a separate question for the rest.

Comment: This program allows me to download  one image, m'y question is how to upload multiple images?

Comment: @JonnyD gave the correct answer for this question. Did you try to implement it? If you have a different question I would open a new question instead of proposing totally different questions in the comments.

Comment: yes, i implemented this programm!thank's

Comment: @GhaliaDehag , be so nice then, to hook it off as 'solved', and give the guy the appr. score.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any error messages?  My first thought would be that your file path is wrong:

```
string name = format("/home//ghalia//essai3//essai3/src//dossierimages//.jpg", i);
```

Those are a lot of weird places for forward slashes and you don't have a basename for the .jpg extension.  It's likely that you intend the jpg to be named by the loop index.

I'm not familiar with your format() function, but try this:

```
string name = format("/home/ghalia/essai3/essai3/src/dossierimages/%d.jpg", i);
```